# LTspice giving incorrect voltage value for simple first order low pass RC filter

Tags: simulation, low-pass

I drew this low pass filter circuit to have a output voltage of 5v across capacitor at a frequency of 100Hz sine wave of amplitude 10v. 
But I am only getting 4.5 volt as output in steady state. I am doing simulation in LTspice on Ubuntu. What mistake I am making?

R = sqrt(3)/(2*pi*fC) - This is how I calculated R for a given C to have a half voltage drop across C

[image]

Comment: The \$\sqrt 3\$ term is not part of the calculation for this type of circuit.

Comment: How did you read this 4.5V ?? I get 4.9956V in my LTspice.

Comment: @G36 - My LTSpice gives somewhere around 4.60 volt. Don't know why? I did a transient analysis for 8 second.

Comment: @G36:- When I put exactly 200ms as you did in transient, I am getting the correct value. I think I am making something related to transient timing? Can't I use a large value for stop time in transient analysis, like 10 seconds?

Comment: @InQusitive try set Maximum Timestep at around 10us in transient analysis window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 5V peak from a 10V peak supply across \$1 \mu F\$ capacitor at 100Hz we need current equal to
I = 5V/Xc = 5V/1.592kOhm = 3.1407mA and the voltage drop across resistor is
$$V_R = \sqrt{(10V^2 - 5V^2)} = 8.66V peak $$
therefore
$$R = \frac{8.66V}{3.1407mA} =2.757k\Omega $$
So yes, your calculations are correct.
And the simulation result look like this
[image]

As you can see the peak voltage is 5V but RMS value is around 3.5V